# Service registers itself with weird hostname at eureka

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm just exploring the Spring Cloud stack. I've set up an Eureka instance and then set up a service that registers itself with Eureka.

Eureka:

appliation.properties

```
spring.application.name=registry
server.port=8761

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class RegistryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RegistryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Service:
application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=example-service
server.port=1111    
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@RestController
public class AppServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppServiceApplication.class, args);
    }


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayHi() {
        return "Hi";
    }

}
```

Now both eureka and the service are starting up and the service registers itself with eureka as expected. However it registers itself with a rather weird hostname and I am not able to figure out what exactly is going on or why this is happening. This is a screenshot of the eureka dashboard showing the weird hostname: 
[image: Eureka Dashboard Screenshot]

I tried the same setup on my laptop and there the hostname is just 'localhost' as expected. 
 
Does someone have an explanation for this ? Thank you in advance for your answers!


Edit: I'm using Spring Boot version 2.0.5.RELEASE